# how to use a subdomain for a website when it has another SRV record on it

Tags: dns, subdomain, srv-records

I am hosting a Mineraft server on the port 25601 and because I didn't want users to have to type the port in, I made a SRV record in my DNS settings so that `minecraft.mydomain.com` points to `mydomain.com:25601`.

(using this DNS configuration: `_minecraft._tcp.minecraft.mydomain.com` pointing to port `25601` on `mydomain.com`)

Now, I want to host a website on minecraft.mydomain.com, giving users info about my Minecraft server.

How could I do this?

```
note:  I don't really want to have to host either on a different subdomain.
```

Comment: SRV records are service specific.  When you create them you have to enter a "symbolic name" for the service.   I believe you can have several SRV records for each subdomain, each for a different service.   I think you can also create a regular "A" record for that subdomain for protocols like HTTP/HTTPS that don't use SRV records.  I haven't found any clear references for these beliefs, however.

Answer (score -1):

Since [browsers do not take into account SRV records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records), just add A and AAAA records on `minecraft.mydomain.com`

Comment: He's using SRV for the minecraft game server, not for something that a browser would use.   Minecraft clients do use SRV records, so that is fine.   His question is whether or not the same server can be used as a web server and whether or not additional DNS records can be added using the same host name.

Comment: The question was how to have a webserver on the same name so like I replied he just needs to have a/aaaa records for the name and this is orthogonal to the srv stuff needed only by Minecraft I never supposed otherwise . The question was really on the name to use  do not infer things from.question.

Comment: Do you have references or experience that the SRV records are indeed orthogonal?

Comment: See my answer: browsers do not use SRV records at all

Comment: And adding the A record won't mess up the Minecraft server?